# Out of nowhere, my frames became connected, and now I cannot edit my frames! Any changes I make apply to all of them

Tags: animation, keyframes, error

[image: Connected Keyframes]

As you can see, the Keyframes have become connected, and this is still relatively new. I can open up old Animations and the keyframes aren't connected, and I can edit them. If I then try to add new frames, It will connect to the others. I am relatively new to Blender so I need explanations. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you have two keyframes with no change in their values, a dark yellow line connects them. When the values are different the line goes away. It is meant for you to know if there is a pause or a "hold" on the motion or whatever animated parameter you are displaying.

on the image all of the keframes are selected (showing as yellow). To edit just one deselect all and then just select the one you want to change.

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice to know. However, I still cannot change the frames, any edits I make apply to all the frames connected, making animation impossible. Would you have any remedy for this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 3.1.2. also and you can use auto keyframe on timeline (the white circle) to edit your animations. Here is the developer page:
https://developer.blender.org/T60598

Comment: This question was first asked nearly 2 years ago. I don't think 3.1.2 was a thing then.

Comment: I noticed that later on but I was thinking it may work for other versions.